# place a button randomly in layout

Tags: java, android, button, if-statement, random

my code works like this:buttongame1 is the place where start_time moves on the next i . But buttongame1 should choose it's place randomly, and it does this, but not on i == 0 , so everytime when I open the activity, buttongame1 is not randomly placed

```
public void onClick(View v) {

         textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.over);

        Random r = new Random();

        RelativeLayout decorView = (RelativeLayout) buttongame1.getParent();

        int screenWidth = decorView.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = decorView.getHeight();



          if(v == gameover){


              i--;

                btncounter.setText("GAME OVER");
                start_time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttongame1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
                anim.setDuration(50); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
                anim.setStartOffset(20);
                anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
                anim.setRepeatCount(123);
                textview1.startAnimation(anim);
                Toast.makeText(this, "GAME OVER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                over1.start();



                        finish();


                    }

          if (i == 0 ) {
                btncounter.setText("0");

                //int x0 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
                //int y0 = (int) buttongame1.getY();


            }
          i++;

        if (i == 1 ) {
            btncounter.setText("1");
             startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
             int x1 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
                int y1 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
                start_time.setX(x1);
                start_time.setY(y1);
                 buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - buttongame1.getHeight()));
                    buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));

                    mp1.start();
        }
        if (i == 2 ) {
            btncounter.setText("2");
            int x2 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y2 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
            start_time.setX(x2);
            start_time.setY(y2);
             buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - buttongame1.getHeight()));
            buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
            mp2.start();
        }
        if (i == 3 ) {
            btncounter.setText("3");
            int x3 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y3 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
            start_time.setX(x3);
            start_time.setY(y3);
             buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - buttongame1.getHeight()));
            buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
            mp3.start();
        }
        if (i == 4 ) {
            btncounter.setText("4");
            int x4 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y4 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
            start_time.setX(x4);
            start_time.setY(y4);
             buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - buttongame1.getHeight()));
            buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
            mp4.start();
        }
        if (i == 5 ) {
            btncounter.setText("5");
            int x5 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y5 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
            start_time.setX((x5));
            start_time.setY(y5);
             buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - buttongame1.getHeight()));
            buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
            mp5.start();
        }
        if (i == 6 ) {
            btncounter.setText("6");
            int x6 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y6 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
            start_time.setX(x6);
            start_time.setY(y6);
             buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - buttongame1.getHeight()));
            buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
            mp6.start();
        }
        if (i == 7 ) {
            btncounter.setText("7");
            int x7 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y7 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
            start_time.setX(x7);
            start_time.setY(y7);
             buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - buttongame1.getHeight()));
            buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
            mp7.start();
        }
        if (i == 8 ) {
            btncounter.setText("8");
            int x8 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y8 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
            start_time.setX(x8);
            start_time.setY(y8);
             buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - buttongame1.getHeight()));
            buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - buttongame1.getWidth()));
            mp8.start();
        }
        if (i == 9 ) {
            btncounter.setText("9");
            int x9 = (int) buttongame1.getX();
            int y9 = (int) buttongame1.getY();
            start_time.setX(x9);
            start_time.setY(y9);
            mp9.start();


        }

        else if (i == 10) {
            mp10.start();
            btncounter.setText("10");
            start_time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttongame1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            long difference = (System.currentTimeMillis()  - startTime);



            String thetime = String.format("%d,%03d sec",difference/1000,difference%1000);

            Toast.makeText(this, (thetime), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put the (i =0) before the onClick was called. as I did so, everything worked fine.

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button start_time;
    Button buttongame1;
    int i;


       Random r;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
          start_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_time);
          start_time.setOnClickListener(this);
          textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.over);
          gameover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gameover);
          gameover.setOnClickListener(this);

          i = 0;
          r = new Random();
       buttongame1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttongame1);
       btn_start2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start2);


         smthin();  


    }


    public void smthin() {


         DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
          getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
          int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
          int Width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


                    try { 

                        if (i == 0) {
                      buttongame1.setX(r.nextInt(Width - buttongame1.getHeight()));
                        buttongame1.setY(r.nextInt(height - buttongame1.getWidth()));

                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    }
```

followed by the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1):

u don't have any code for i==0, set random position in i==0..